# CSS, table border

Tags: css

If table is set to have a border on a high level, how can i make sure that classes inhering from it do not have any borders set?

```
table,td,th {
    border: 1px solid #0B6121;
}
```

how can i make sure that my other table has no borders at all?

```
table.menu {
    border: none;
    - and no border for td
    - and no border for th
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.main, table.menu td, table.menu td {
    border: none;
}
```

This way I guess. The idea is to set rules for siblings of your particular table.

Comment: i figured this much :) any way to put it all under the umbrella of table.menu?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, group them by classes or style with unique ids. I prefer to use unique ids for some special unique styling - but it depends on how do you like to code styles :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
table.menu, .menu th, .menu td {
    border:none;
}
```

sometyhing like this?

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
table.menu td, table.menu tr{
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code stands

```
<table class="menu"></table>
```

will not have an outside border, but any th and td elements inside will inherit the border from your global selector.

The other answers that demonstrate applying specific rules to the td and th elements inside of a table with class of 'menu' should help you out.